# Why does my JQuery click event won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to link this button with `#analyzebutton` id

```
<div class="pd-upload-foto">
     <div class="vertical-center text-center">
          <button id="startbutton" class='btn btn-ambilfoto btn-sm btn-1 font-3' style='padding-top:.2rem; padding-bottom:.2rem;' type='button'>ambil foto</button>
           <button id="analyzebutton" class='btn btn-sm btn-1 font-3' style='padding-top:.2rem; padding-bottom:.2rem; display: none;' type='button'>mulai analisis</button>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="pd-analisa" style="display: none;">
                <div class="vertical-center text-center">
                    <button id="analyzingbutton" class='btn btn-sm btn-1 font-3' style='padding-top:.2rem; padding-bottom:.2rem;' type='button'>mulai analisa</button>
                    <img id="tesfotomasuk" src="" alt="tes aja">
                </div>
 </div>
```

with this JQuery script

```
$(".btn-ambilfoto").click(function() {
     $(".btn-ambilfoto").html("berhasil").attr("disabled", "true");
     $(".btn-ambilfoto").removeClass("btn-1").addClass("btn-4");
     $("#analyzebutton").show();
});

$("#analyzebutton").click(function() {
     $(".pd-upload-foto").hide();
     $(".pd-analisa").show();

     $("#analyzingbutton").html("Analyzing...");
});
```

When I press the `#analyzebutton` button, it should fire the on click function and executes the function, but it doesn't. It's

I also have linked the JQuery script and the JS script at bottom of the html file.

Somehow, `#analyzebutton` is the only that doesn't work. The `.btn-ambilfoto` button (located just above the `#analyzebutton`) works without problem.

I've tried to change the code to `$(selector).on("click", function(){})` but it doesn't work either.

How should I fix this? I've spent more than 6 hours to just to fix this.

Comment: I was trying to suggest that your issue is that the you have that element hidden with `display: none`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt none works. I have tried those methods before.

Comment: @freedomn-m Tried it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does your button get shown?  If you add this inside the .btn-ambilfoto click handler, what does it give: `console.log($("#analyzebutton").length)` - what does it give if you add it right before `$("#analyzebutton").click(` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m The `#analyzebutton` gets shown after I click the `btn-ambilfoto` button. Tried adding that console log but neither gives me any output.

Comment: *"neither gives any output"* - no error, no "0" or "1"?  No output at all?  Then I would suggest the code isn't being called.

Comment: @freedomn-m Nope. But if I run the console.log on browser console, it gives me "1".

Comment: `$("#id").click` will only apply to elements that exist at the time the code runs (assuming the code runs), so trying to establish that the element exists at that time, which it appears it doesn't, or your code is simply not running.  `$(document).on("click", "#analyzebutton", function() ..` would the code to use if it's created later ("dynamically created").   But if you're code isn't even running...

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks very much for your help but I think I found the issues. I just opened the debugger on Chrome but somehow the JS script doesn't call `#analyzebutton` (just like what you said), it calls `#analyzingbutton` (this was the previous ID I used). This is very weird, if this is the case, why does it not run the latest saved script (I have saved it multiple times, I also pushed it to my github)? I just reopened Chrome, Firefox, and VS Code but somehow it still runs that old saves (not the latest one). It uses the latest html, css, but it doesn't use the latest js. Why?

Comment: Try control-F5 or open the page with console open and debugger set to disable cache (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/2181514)

Comment: Glad you found the issue (code not running) and hope you can find the cause.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks very much! It works! The code runs now! Can't believe it's because of that thing. I have to try to use debugger more now (gotta admit, I forgot about debugging)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser runs the previous saves (not the latest one) where it doesn't call `#analyzebutton` and calls another button instead. Thanks to @freedomn-m and [this SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development/7000899#7000899), disabling the cache on the browser fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is inside the document.ready function. That might be the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".btn-ambilfoto").click(function() {
        $(".btn-ambilfoto").html("berhasil").attr("disabled", "true");
        $(".btn-ambilfoto").removeClass("btn-upself-1").addClass("btn-upself-4");
        $("#analyzebutton").show();
    });
    
    $("#analyzebutton").click(function() {
        $(".pd-upload-foto").hide();
        $(".pd-analisa").show();
    
        $("#analyzingbutton").html("Analyzing...");
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work.